# How to add toggle button at column level in Oracle Business Intelligence 11.1.1.9.0 (OBIEE)

Tags: oracle, obiee

I'm new to Oracle Business Intelligence 11.1.1.9.0  (OBIEE).

I want to add a toggle button (+) at the column of the report.

By default, the report should display single value and Once if the user clicks the plus symbol it should expand to show other values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is a hierarchical column / a dimensional hierarchy. https://gerardnico.com/dat/obiee/obis/hierarchy

I highly suggest you get properly trained because using by far the most powerful analytics solution with the most modeling capabilities "just like that" is a recipe for disaster-